# JavaFX can't settext() on Final TextField

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, textfield, settext

I'm unable to set TextField if variable TextField is set as final but if i change it to private or public it changes text of my textfiel. I thought that final just don't allow create another instance of class. I tried print HashCode of both private and final TextField but they was not changing. So im curious why i have to have private or public TextField to SetText() to it.

```
public class SearchController {

    @FXML
    final TextField textfieldSelectedDirectory = new TextField();
    @FXML
    private Button path;
    @FXML
    private Label pathlabel;
    @FXML
    final TextField searchfield = new TextField();

    public String getSearchfield() {

        return searchfield.getText();
    }

    private MainApp mainApp;
    private Stage stage;

    public SearchController() {

    }

    @FXML
    private void Index() {

        IndexFiles.index();

    }

    @FXML
    private void search() {

        SearchFiles().Search();
        System.out.println(searchfield.hashCode());

        System.out.println("Somtu");

        System.out.println(getSearchfield());

    }

    private void setPath(File selectedDirectory) {
        String dir = selectedDirectory.getAbsolutePath();


        pathlabel.setText(dir);

        textfieldSelectedDirectory.clear();

        // textfieldSelectedDirectory.getParent().layout();

        System.out.println(textfieldSelectedDirectory.getText());
    }
}
```

Thank's you for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an `FXMLLoader` loads an FXML file, it

1. Creates an instance of the controller class specified by `fx:controller`
2. Creates instances of the classes described by the elements in the FXML file (i.e. for `<Button>` it creates a `Button` instance, etc), and sets their properties
3. For elements with a `fx:id` attributes, sets the corresponding `@FXML`-injected field in the controller instance that was created
4. Registers event handlers, etc.
5. Calls the `initialize()` method on the controller

Since the `@FXML` fields are set *after* the constructor call has completed, they cannot be `final`. Additionally, it doesn't make sense to initialize them since they are going to be set by the `FXMLLoader` anyway: you should **never** initialize `@FXML`-annotated fields.

So your field declarations should be

```
@FXML
TextField textfieldSelectedDirectory ;
```

etc, (and you can, and probably should, make these `private` too).

The `final` keyword simply means that the variable is assigned a value exactly once. While this is technically true in the set up I describe (the field is only ever assigned a value once, by the `FXMLLoader`), the compiler needs to know this in order for the code to compile, and since it cannot possibly know what the `FXMLLoader` is going to do with instances of your controller class, you cannot make these fields `final`.

Comment: Thank's you very much. Compiler let me run it only thing that was not working was SetText() or setPromptText() but i was able to get value if i wrote something to TextField. I have clear now thank's you again. But im still curious why compiler let me run it?

Comment: Your code compiles because it follows all the normal rules: you have `final` fields, and they are assigned values exactly once. The `FXMLLoader` will attempt to assign new values to those fields via reflection (so there are no compiler checks), and fails (I'm surprised there is no stack trace, or at least a warning), so the fields are not reassigned. So when you call `setText(..)` you are invoking it on the initial text field you set in the controller initializer, not on the one you specified in the FXML (i.e. not on the one that is displayed).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `final` variables in combination with FXML injection. With FXML the fields will be created after the call of the constructor. So you would have to remove the `new TextField()` initialization.
The compiler won't let you though.